# rails 4 put and post request in one form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails 4 app the user gets started by signing in via oauth which creates a new record in the users table. The next step the user enters keywords in a form which consists of five fields plus a sixth field for their email address. Upon submission, how do I tell rails to update their record in the users table with their email address and save their keywords to the keywords table? Is this possible because I don't think you can do a post and put request in the same submit. If not, do I create a separate table for user email addresses? What is the best solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this [PUT vs POST in REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest)

Why can't you do it all in the same request?

Comment: thanks... i didn't know a put can create a record. I thought it was only for updating. so in my example I would use put to save new records and update an existing record all in the same request.

Comment: Cheers mate! let me know if I can help with anything else.

Comment: You can create a record even with GET, but is not a good choice.